# CentOS 6.7 Root user home deleted?

Tags: linux, centos

Some how I managed to delete the `/root` directory, so I went and recreated and set the proper permissions to the file directory. However, my command line is different and instead of showing `root@my-machine#` I get `-bash-4.1#`.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you deleted /root and now you have -bash-4.1# in your command line huh?

Well this is caused of a missing / corrupt .bashrc (in your case missing) file in /root (.bashrc sources /etc/bashrc which is what sets the prompt). To fix it, you will run the following command which runs when an account is created. **Run as the root user** (since it is the user having the problem) **or you can define the destination path.**

command: (make sure you are in /root)

```
cp -v /etc/skel/.bash* ~/
```

Exit terminal and log back in.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by creating a new `.bashrc`

Because the `/root` directory was removed the default `.bashrc` was deleted.

I fixed it by running
`/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`
and then sourcing the new `.bashrc` file with `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: The disappointment was real when I finished my answer and you already answered it ;(

Comment: @CodyRobinson Sorry! D: